capturing output from a command in R
I'm trying to calculate the duration of audio files using the seewave package in R, which sends a command to an audio software program called sox. While the duration is printed in my R console, there appears to be no way of capturing the outputted time in seconds.
I ran the following command in R, where flac is a path to my flac file:
seewave::sox(stringr::str_glue("--i -D {flac}"), path2exe = "C:/Program Files (x86)/sox-14-4-2")
This prints the duration of the audio file, and a 0 afteward:
3600.384000
[1] 0
I've tried to capture the output using sink(), capture.output(), etc. but I can only ever capture the printed '0', and not the duration of the audio file.

sox is a convenience wrapper around a system() call. You could either write your own system2(stdout = TRUE, ...)-call to your executable or use capture.output(sox(...)).

This works instead:
a <- system('soxi -D input.flac', intern = TRUE)  
print(a)

